# Is there a File.basename with case-insensitive suffix?

Tags: ruby

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html

```
File.basename("/home/gumby/work/Hello.txt")           #=> "Hello.txt"
File.basename("/home/gumby/work/Hello.txt", ".txt")   #=> "Hello"
```

Is there a API for case-insensitive suffix? I'd like the following:

```
File.basename("/home/gumby/work/Hello.TXT", ".txt")   #=> "Hello.TXT"
```

to return `"Hello"`, instead of `"Hello.TXT"` or `"hello"`.

Comment: Can't you just downcase (upcase) everything? Do you really need the original case?

Comment: Yes, I need to original case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. However, the really platform-independent part of File.basename lies in the path manipulation, not so much the suffix. You can therefore easily replace the suffix removal by a sub:

```
File.basename(my_path).sub(/\.txt$/i, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

How is it?

```
File.basename("ab.TXT","txt".upcase)
#=> "ab."
File.basename("ab.txt","TXT".downcase)
#=> "ab."
```

Comment: See comments under the question.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev what he asked to see, I did the same. Of course one thing `File.basename("/home/gumby/work/Hello.TXT", ".txt")   #=> "Hello.TXT"` never possible. it will give only the file name, i.e. `Hello`. The thing remains extension matching. As per his question answer is correct.

Comment: At the time of my downvote, the question was clear. But later, a controversy has been introduced. Therefore I withdraw the downvote. :)

Comment: _Of course one thing File.basename("/home/gumby/work/Hello.TXT", ".txt") #=> "Hello.TXT" never possible_ <- Have you run the code?

Answer (score -1):

```
File.basename(file, File.extname(file))
```

Comment: That will remove the file extension no matter what it is.

Comment: That's exactly what I want, remove case-insensitive suffix.

Comment: That s different from what you have in the question.

Comment: @sawa Yes you are right! His question and answer conflicting.